# JQuery fileupload on click

Tags: jquery

Instead of using input type file for fileupload, I want to use a clickable div that calls the normal fileupload like the input did.

```
instead of this
<input type="file"/> 

I want this
<div>Click to upload</div>
and paste the file path in the div
```

Comment: _"and paste the file path in the div"_ what does that mean?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMqK9/) might help you

Comment: Yeah I don't really get the question either. Maybe he wants to pass the input file name and replace the divs contents with that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idea:

When the user click the div, call the click event on the file input and when it change, insert the html on the div

on the div

```
 $('#magicdiv').click(function(){
 $('#leupload').click();
  });
```

on the upload file

```
$('#leupload').change(function(){
$('#magicdiv').html( $(this).val() );
});
```